# How would I check if my bot is in a voice channel? Discord.py

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

[Image of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVX3e.png)

Im trying to check if my bot is in a voice channel. Although for some reason voice_client always returns as None. Even when its in a vc. Why?

Answer (score 0):

A bit iffy on this answer because I haven't seen the context of the code you provided, but if I am not mistaken, you should use the following for the definition of `voice_client`:`discord.utils.get(ctx.bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)` Additionally, you can use the `is_connected()` function of `voice_client` to find if the bot is connected as a Boolean value.

Comment: Hm this doesnt seem to work. I think it may be because the way im connecting the bot to a vc is by: 
async def connect_to(self, guild_id: int, channel_id: str):
        ws = self.bot._connection._get_websocket(guild_id)
        await ws.voice_state(str(guild_id), channel_id)